# ActionBar style (Text size)

Tags: android

I'm trying to modify the text size of my `ActionBar` and I tried styling it but it doesn't change anything... That's my styles page.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.Styled.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.Styled.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Styled.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
</style>
```

Also I had this on my `styles.xml` but doesn't work either

```
<style name="Theme.FixedSize" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarSize">4dip</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">4dip</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">3sp</item>
</style>
```

I also have tried with a nasty way but it doesn't work only works with the color.

```
 mActionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font size=\"3\" color=\"white\">" + getString(R.string.app_name_device)));
```

After you say to me... I know now it's used `Toolbar` **BUT** I have to do it now with `ActionBar`.

### EDIT

I hided the ActionBar like this :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>
```

Then I added a `ToolBar` like this :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"

    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />
```

But the `Layout` messed up, it goes up and now the `ToolBar` is collapsed with the first `TextView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it programmatically like this

```
Html.fromHtml("<big><font color=\"white\">" + getString(R.string.app_name_device)+"</big>")
```

for small text you can change tag `<big>` with `<small>`

and if you want to provide specific `size` of Title Text then you should use `Toolbar` and use below `theme/style`

Create one layout `toolbar.xml` and put below code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText" />
```

and change `size` in

```
<style name="Toolbar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

and you can `inculde` above layout in your each Activity layout files like below

```
<include
     layout="@layout/toolbar"
             />
```

`Toolbar` in your `Activity`

```
ToolBar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<big><font color=\"white\">" + getString(R.string.app_name_device)+"</big>"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but I actually want to use a number since I use `sdp` and it will addapt to all of my devices (I'm talking about html) if I want to change it to `ToolBar` I have to add this and that's all?

Comment: But I have to hide the ActionBar and show the Toolbar, no?

Comment: you have to put that in relative layout then specify layout_below or use Linear Layout with orientation vertical

Comment: you can post your xml as well which is messed up so i can look into it

Comment: I tried to put the Toolbar on a RelativeLayout and it says : "is not sibling in the same RelativeLayout"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99315/discussion-between-shishram-and-skizo).

Answer (score 1):

I do it so:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;

public void title_change(String text) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(text);
    tv.setTextSize(15);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(tv);
}
```